# Must my name be in the authors of paper (By giving the idea and creating the first research team)

Tags: publications, ethics, paper-submission

I have introduced the idea and basic information of one important research field to one psychology experts.

Also I have created some other connection for that psychology experts by one phd master.

The research field is about the [dark triad personality of humanity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_triad) and its effect on the iranian new revolution at 2022.

So based of this studying, that psychology expert created one three person room and after arouln 3 meeting that the 3 persons have, then I can say they received the idea and the Information, then they created the new room and working on the paper by themselves. I were happy to give them the information and seeing some experts finding the correct scientific way to help the iranian people, but there are some ethical concerns.

So that psychology expert is receiving the academic scholarships for doctors at other university and it was so usefull fit her carrier.
According, for my security and protection against religion and fascism government which killed around 400 people, I prefer my identity be hidden ([more information here](https://www.euronews.com/2022/12/20/iran-protests-what-caused-them-who-is-generation-z-will-the-unrest-lead-to-revolution))

So finally I guess that expert would write some paper and received some scholarships found based of my guidline and When they removed me from the new research group, I think that, my name not be in that research paper.

But I want to know it is ethically to be not my name in the authers of the academic papers which has been written by small team?

I don't say anything because the field of study is so clear and they are working on something which is about the dark and light personality of humans as you can see below ([google search tags link](https://www.google.com/search?q=dark%20vs%20light%20personality%20psychology&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rvo3&sxsrf=AJOqlzWbr5DfdNCiOu04yk32u7x6Hw_CjA%3A1675452766906&ei=XmHdY8j-NqWCxc8P8IK8qAM&oq=dark%20vs%20light%20personality%20psychology&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBwghEKABEAoyBwghEKABEAoyBwghEKABEAo6BAgjECc6BAgAEB46BggAEAgQHjoFCAAQhgM6BQgAEKIEOgYIABAWEB46BQghEKABOggIIRAWEB4QHUoECEEYAFDuFFjJImDCJGgAcAB4AIABlAeIAeAekgEHNC0yLjQuMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp))

> What is dark vs light personality? The light subtype evidenced
> affiliative interpersonal functioning and greater trust in others, as
> well as higher life satisfaction and positive self-image. The dark
> subtype reflected interpersonal dominance, competitiveness, and
> aggression.

Finally I can say their action would be interesting for me because this situation not must be happening and showing my action or their action have some problem and failur.

Also, I suggested many other information and business plans and the reason for this free giving informations is finding light people. This is so warming and hopeful and the main goal.

**Update 1:**

Based of the [answer of **Buffy**](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/193160/75368)

I guess I have removed from the research group not to be in the academic paper too, but I have given the idea of research and added another person with higher degree and given many free consulting in around 3 meeting with every meeting around 1 hour duration, also I have tried to summarizing some papers but not completed that summarizing because of having some personal problem and I am in contact by them but don't ask them about that but I like to know what is the ethics and run of this procedure.

Also, I have engineering and I don't know that I can be an advisor or not, but this idea and information came from another big project.

When I have seen the project has been stoped and even by giving free information and plans and I am donig this project alone.

so I came to find out there must be some reason and find out the dark triad of perianality of humanity is some part of reason and given the information and my researches result, to one psychology experts and created one team for that psychology expert.

It seems that they do not want be any name of me in the paper.

So I asked that will be this action ethical and normal or not?!

So, I asked here to check them.
Finally, I don't want any things from them, but the research field is about the dark and light personality characteristics of hand so it is important to check that the writer of one academic paper about the light personality characteristics as love, empathy, altruism, compassion, corporation and scarification don't believe in those characteristics and act dark by having narcissism, psychopath and Machiavellian in their researches, by breaking the ethical rules or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Did I read it wrong? I thought you wanted to avoid visible authorship in this case. Is it, instead, a case that you believe you are being denied proper authorship? It was a bit hard to understand due to language differences.

Comment: Dear @Buffy , I think I will be denied in the academic paper authers names, and it is important because the paper is about the ethical things like dark triad of humanity like narsistism and light personality as love, corporation and..., So I asked here to know that persons better.

Comment: So, this is not a concern about political risk of being public about the situation in Iran, correct?

Comment: Yes, Dear @Buffy. I know that we could use one false name, but as I have said the paper is about the ethics and it is important to check that the authers of that paper have the right ethics. If they breaks some ethical rights I would stop my connection with them and will invest my time and connection by others groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following was based on an earlier version of the question that I may have misunderstood. I may be able to revise it, perhaps radically, when the editing settles down.

One option is to create an alter-ego, a false name, used for publication purposes where only your co-authors know your true identity. There is no general requirement that publication needs to be under your legal name.

Evaluate whether that would give you sufficient security or not. If, at some future point, the situation changes and you don't need such protections, then the connection with you as an individual could be revealed.

In an extreme case, you can permit others to use your work without specific attribution, though they need to be careful not to make the situation one of plagiarism, suggesting they alone had the important ideas.

In some fields, advisors are not listed as authors on their student's work even though they did, in fact, contribute to it. They are normally acknowledged by name, however, though in an extreme case a carefully chosen false name might be used. Difficult times sometimes require exceptions to the normal rules.

You don't need to follow normal conventions if it puts your life or liberty at risk.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have updated the question and add more information to clearfy the question.